# Changing the clickable state of a button in a layout from another activty

Tags: android, button, android-activity, clickable

I am new to android app development. I am developing a puzzle game with some levels.

I am having a `levelmenu.xml, Levelmenu.java`, and xml and java files of the levels. if the user finishes a level next level should unlock for them.

I am using buttons in `levelmenu.xml` and on clicking a button respective intent will be activated which will open the respective level. each level is a separate activity.

So i want to change the icon and clickable state of the button in levelmenu activity from another activity(the respective level activity).How to do it. please help me.

Comment: i think you can pass `putStringExtra()` in intent and use in next activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a game , I believe that you need to save the user progress somewhere (may be preference).Once you complete a level you can set the progress in a file(preference).
In onResume() method of your Levelmenu activity look the progress in that file and display the  menu buttons accordingly.
By doing so you can also handle the use case of allowing the user to continue from his last progress(level) even after stopping and restarting the app.
*NB- this answer is written specific for this question, may not be useful in other scenarios.*